# spring bean ref from nested import resources

Tags: spring, import, javabeans

I have a spring config file **service.xml**
,which imports **applicationContext.xml** , and my applicationContext.xml imports a **security.xml**.

Now in my **service.xml** have defined a bean say

```
<bean id="mySecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
<property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
<property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken" />
<property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="myPasswordCallbackHandler" />
```

This **myPasswordCallbackHandler 
bean is defined in security.xml**, but while loading up the app context I getting bean definition not found for myPasswordCallbackHandler.

How can reference this **myPasswordCallbackHandler** bean ??

Thanks!

Here is the stackTrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySecurityInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/service.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mySecurityPasswordCallbackHandler' while setting bean property 'validationCallbackHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mySecurityPasswordCallbackHandler' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
... 64 more

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'mySecurityPasswordCallbackHandler' is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:527)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1083)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:274)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:266)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
```

Here are my myPasswordCallbackHandler def:

```
<beans:bean id="myPasswordCallbackHandler"
  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
<beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the myPasswordCallbackHandler definition? And the exact error (it might have some other useful information)?

Comment: this should work, can you provide more info?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have a typo somewhere, there are references in your post to two beans: `mySecurityPasswordCallbackHandler` and `myPasswordCallbackHandler`. Make sure you are using the right name.

Comment: or, he can also omit the validationCallbackHandler property on mySecurityInterceptor and set autowire="byType", assuming myPasswordCallbackHandler is the only instance of that type.

Comment: @Beau: Yup, typo while editing the stacktrace, since these r not real bean names. Consider mySecurityPasswordCallbackHandler  to be myPasswordCallbackHandler.

Comment: @user620339 So you are saying that all the references/definitions are either `mySecurityPasswordCallbackHandler` or `myPasswordCallbackHandler` in your code?

Comment: Does it matter from how much nested import i am referencing a bean.

Comment: You say that the definition and the reference are in the same security.xml file - nesting is not an issue here.

Comment: No, definition is in security.xml and reference is in service.xml

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but can you try an explicit depends-on

```
<bean id="mySecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor" depends-on="myPasswordCallbackHandler">
<property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
<property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken" />
<property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="myPasswordCallbackHandler" />
```

Assuming you have a bean called myPasswordCallbackHandler and all import statements are proper, I don't see any issue with the usage.